# cannot install flutter_plugins_tools, dependency error

Tags: dart, flutter

When I try to install plugin tools with

`pub global activate flutter_plugin_tools`

I get this error.

> flutter git:(master) ✗ pub global activate flutter_plugin_tools 
>   Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)  Package http has no versions that
>   match >=0.11.3+13 <0.12.0 derived from:
>   - flutter_plugin_tools 0.0.1-dev depends on version ^0.11.3+13

Comment: This question got filed on GitHub, if anyone is running into this issue please follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11075 for updates.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably old Dart SDKs that are in your path. Check your path and remove them.

Originally answered on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11075) by Devin Carew:

> If you're running `pub global activate` directly, it's using the version
>   of the dart sdk that's on your path, which may be different than the
>   version shipped with flutter (you can run `dart --version` to see the
>   version on your path). I suspect that you have an old version of dart,
>   and pub is having trouble resolving a version of package:http that
>   will work with it. You'll probably want to update your path to include
>   `path/to/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin`, or could try running `flutter packages pub global activate flutter_plugin_tools`.